# How do I prove this statement about limits?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ is monotonic increasing and $b_n$ is a Bounded series and the limit of $a_n$ - $b_n$ is zero then prove that $b_n$ has a limit.I know that if I proved that $b_n$ is monotonic increasing/decreasing then the question will be solved because monotonic and bounded sequences always have a limit but I couldnt prove that.Any piece of advice will be appreciated.

Comment: by blocked do you mean bounded?

Comment: yes.I just got confused with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(b_n)$ is bounded, so there's $M > 0$ such that $|b_n| \le M$, $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb N$.

$(a_n - b_n)$ is convergent to $0$, so:

$\exists \ n_0 \in \mathbb N$, such that $\forall$ $n \ge n_0, $|a_n - b_n| < 1$. Hence:

$|a_n| = |a_n - b_n + b_n| \le |a_n - b_n| + |b_n| < 1 + M$, for all $n \ge n_0$.

Let $W = \max(|a_1|, |a_2|, \ldots, |a_{n_0 - 1}|, 1 + M)$. Then:

$|a_n| \le W$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Thus, $(a_n)$ is bounded and increasing, and so convergent to some $a \in \mathbb R$.

Next, prove that $\lim b_n = a$: let $\epsilon > 0$.

$a_n \longrightarrow a \implies \exists \ n_1 \in \mathbb N$ for which $|a_n - a| < \epsilon / 2$, for all $n \ge n_1$.

$(a_n - b_n)$ converges to $0$, so $\exists$ $n_2 \in \mathbb N$ for which: $|a_n - b_n| < \epsilon / 2$, for all $n \ge n_2$.

Let $n_3 = \max(n_1, n_2)$, then for all $n \ge n_3$:

$|b_n - a| = |b_n - a_n + a_n - a| \le |b_n - a_n| + |a_n - a| < \epsilon /2 + \epsilon /2 = \epsilon$.

Comment: Great answer.Thx

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_n - b_n$ converges it is bounded.  Thus $a_n = (a_n - b_n) + b_n$ is a sum of two bounded sequences, so it is also bounded. Every monotone bounded sequence converges, so $a_n$ has a limit. Since $b_n = a_n - (a_n - b_n)$ the limit law states $$b_n \to a + 0 = a$$ where $a$ is the limit of $a_n$.